# Validating Spring Integration service-activator expression

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We have too many service-activators in our application:

```
<int:service-activator 
        input-channel="operationCompletedChannel" 
        expression="@operationManager.operationCompleted(payload.payload, 
                                                         payload.internalRequestId,
                                                         payload.isSuccess)"/>
```

Some of them are rarely used, so if we made a mistake like a typo, most likely we'll notice it very late. Is there a way like ckecking/validating existence of the method at least.
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

To check mistakes and typos, it would be better to cover all your components with unit tests before publishing your product to the customer.

For example here it would be enough easy: just `mock` your `operationManager` and send any appropriate message to the `operationCompletedChannel`. If your SpEL is bad the `verify` on the mock will say you about that. Or you end up with an `Exception`.

It's really bad to get an issue very late...

Comment: Your solution seems to be best but what I'm looking for is a start-up option that controls expressions against beans.